# Dimensions/ 3D model of Pebble SmartWatch Magnetic Charging Cable

Tags: pebble-watch

I'm trying to design a simple dock for my 1st generation original Pebble smartwatch. Where can I find the dimensions/ drawings of the magnetic connector charging cable?

Answer (score 0):

All the files published by Pebble are in the [pebble-3d](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-3d) GitHub project.

Answer (score 0):

Pebble have 3d models of the original, steel and the new time smartwatch on [GitHub](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-3d). The don't have charger models just yet however you can get models of existing docks on [Thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=pebble%20dock) and model the charger from them